# Why some of the List methods are not recognized by eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, list, arraylist

As shown in the code below, when using `mFragList.add`the method `add` is getting marked by red squiggle. why although I have another project uses the same method to add `fragments` but eclipse recognizes it?

***To Note: ***

> when hover over the red squiggle eclipse says `The method add(Fragment) in the type List<Fragment> is not applicable for the arguments (Fragment02)`.
>
> All of `Fragment01(), Fragment02(), Fragment03() extend Fragment

Java_Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.viewpagerwithactiontabstest00.adapter.MyTabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Fragment> mFragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        mFragList.add(new Fragment01());
        mFragList.add(new Fragment02());
        mFragList.add(new Fragment03());

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyTabsPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new MyTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

   }
}
```

Comment: go with you mouse to the red squiggle. Eclipse shows you the message why it is marked.

Comment: @Jens yes, I updated the question and added a note. please read it

Comment: Looks like the classes `FragmentXX` are not subclasses of `Fragment` so you can not add them to a `List` that only can add `Fragment`

Comment: @Jens Fragment01() is a class extends Fragment

Comment: @Elpharaoh: but what about `Fragment02`?

Comment: And the superclass of Fragment01 is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` not a `Fragment`class from another package?

Comment: @Elpharaoh Can you add the code of Fragment1 please

Comment: Why do you keep writing the class name as `Fragment01()`?